# how to merge/group a XML-document based on a child node

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery

I wonder how to merge/group/combine XML-elements by their content so that the grouped values occure only once and the rest of the node is merged into the result, just like one would group results in modern SQL-dialects like MariaDB (without having duplicates in the results).

I already searched for a solution but the given examples here or somewhere else do not match my requirements - also not after adjusting them.
I guess that the position of `<lemma>` might be a problem. On the other hand, I think/hope that a solution would still be possible somehow.

The simplified structure of my documents and the desired output:

**XML:**

```xml
<root>
  <artikel>
    <lemma-position>
      <lemma>Abend</lemma>
      <info>aaa</info>
    </lemma-position>
    <bedeutungsposition nr="1a">
      <bedeutung>Zeit am Ende des Tages</bedeutung>
    </bedeutungsposition>
    <bedeutungsposition nr="1b">
      <bedeutung>
        was anderes
      </bedeutung>
    </bedeutungsposition>
  </artikel>
  <artikel>
    <lemma-position>
      <lemma>Abend</lemma>
      <info>bbb</info>
    </lemma-position>
    <bedeutungsposition nr="1">
      <bedeutung>abcdefg</bedeutung>
    </bedeutungsposition>
    <bedeutungsposition nr="2">
      <bedeutung>japoisdfoiasjdfoasjdfl</bedeutung>
    </bedeutungsposition>
  </artikel>
</root>
```

In this example, the node `<lemma>` contains "Abend" and this should be the value for grouping.

**desired output:**

```xml
<root>
  <artikel>
    <lemma-position>
      <lemma>Abend</lemma>
      <info>aaa</info>
      <info>bbb</lemma>
    </lemma-position>
    <bedeutungsposition nr="1">
      <bedeutung>abcdefg</bedeutung>
    </bedeutungsposition>
    <bedeutungsposition nr="1a">
      <bedeutung>Zeit am Ende des Tages</bedeutung>
    </bedeutungsposition>
    <bedeutungsposition nr="1b">
      <bedeutung>
        was anderes
      </bedeutung>
    </bedeutungsposition>
    <bedeutungsposition nr="2">
      <bedeutung>japoisdfoiasjdfoasjdfl</bedeutung>
    </bedeutungsposition>
  </artikel>
</root>
```

What I get is an unmerged copy, i.e. the XML-input, or a chunk of it but not merged at all. I have tried several things by now of which the base always is something like:

```xsl
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="artikel" group-by="//lemma">
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()//lemma/*" />
      <!--
        I also placed some other paths and expressions here or above to 
        select the elements differently, without success however.  
      -->
    </xsl:for-each-group>

  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I also tried xQuery with `distinct-values` etc. but it didn't work either (without having duplicates).

I'm testing with Oxygen and baseX, both connecting to Saxon-9.8 HE, so this should be fine actually. A solution in XSLT would be appreciated as much as one in xQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main template would be

```
  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="artikel" group-by="lemma-position/lemma">
              <xsl:copy>
                  <lemma-position>
                      <lemma>
                          <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                      </lemma>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/lemma-position/(* except lemma)"/>
                  </lemma-position>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/(* except lemma-position)">
                      <xsl:sort select="@nr"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

together with identity transformation (e.g. in XSLT 3 declared by `xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"`) you get https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQfR:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="artikel" group-by="lemma-position/lemma">
              <xsl:copy>
                  <lemma-position>
                      <lemma>
                          <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                      </lemma>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/lemma-position/(* except lemma)"/>
                  </lemma-position>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/(* except lemma-position)">
                      <xsl:sort select="@nr"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In BaseX XQuery you could use

```
<root>
{
    for $artikel in root/artikel
    group by $lemma := $artikel/lemma-position/lemma
    return
        <artikel>
           <lemma-position>
             <lemma>{$lemma}</lemma>
             {
                 $artikel/lemma-position/(* except lemma)
             }
           </lemma-position>
           {
               sort($artikel/(* except lemma-position), (), function($el) { $el/@nr })
           }
        </artikel>
}
</root>
```

Comment: thank you so much, Martin! It works like a charm and isn't that complicated. Awesome :)